# Error received when downloading a file from web when only submit button is present

Tags: vba, excel

I need to download a file from web, but only a submit button is present.
There is no url for reaching the file directly.
I tried to catch the button by its id, but VBA drops run-time error '424' (Object required).
Here is the code:

```
Sub keler_submit()  
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False  
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")  
    IE.navigate "https://www.keler.hu/T%C3%A1rsas%C3%A1gi%20esem%C3%A9nyek/"  
    While IE.Busy  
        DoEvents  
    Wend  
    Set doc = IE.document  
    gomb = doc.getElementById("ctl00_wpm_UserControlPortlet1682286671_ctl00_wpm_UserControlPortlet1682286671_userControlPortlet_DownloadButton1")  
    gomb.submit  
    Set IE = Nothing  
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True  
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

These lines are incorrect:

```
gomb = doc.getElementById("ctl00_wpm_UserControlPortlet1682286671_ctl00_wpm_UserControlPortlet1682286671_userControlPortlet_DownloadButton1")  
gomb.submit
```

doc.getElementById returns an object type so you need to use Set to assign it to a variable. The element you are trying to access should then be clicked instead of submitted. There's a high probability that IE will display a "Do you wish to open or save this file" dialog so start by making the IE object visible to show this:

```
IE.visible = True
Set gomb = doc.getElementById("ctl00_wpm_UserControlPortlet1682286671_ctl00_wpm_UserControlPortlet1682286671_userControlPortlet_DownloadButton1")  
gomb.click
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop in there as well to ensure page has loaded. The following works:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.keler.hu/T%C3%A1rsas%C3%A1gi%20esem%C3%A9nyek/"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Do
            Dim b As Object
            On Error Resume Next
            Set b = .document.getElementById("ctl00_wpm_UserControlPortlet1682286671_ctl00_wpm_UserControlPortlet1682286671_userControlPortlet_DownloadButton1")
            On Error GoTo 0
        Loop While b Is Nothing

        b.Click
        'Handle save button

        'Quit '<== Remember to quit application
    End With
End Sub
```